# Android Intent.SEND with text and link to messenger won't work

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-messenger

```
 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        sharingIntent.setType("text/plain");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject Here");
        sharingIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "SHARE BODY https://www.messenger.com");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "HUO"));
```

This text will be shared correctly for other apps, but messenger will only share the URL. Why? How can I fix this?

Comment: Because Facebook doesn't want you to prefill text. We want the user to type the text. So there is nothing you can do to change it

Answer (score 1):

> This text will be shared correctly for other apps

*Some* apps might support that. Apps do not have to, as what you are doing (using *both* `EXTRA_TEXT` and `EXTRA_STREAM`) is outside the scope of [the `ACTION_SEND` contract](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND). You are supposed to use *either* `EXTRA_TEXT` *or* `EXTRA_STREAM`, not both.

> How can I fix this?

Get rid of `EXTRA_TEXT`, or get rid of `EXTRA_STREAM`, or live with random results from apps with your existing `Intent` structure.